# Reload Instance Variable Hot Wire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, hotwire-rails

I have a product counter in my index.html.erb as follows:

```
<p class='text-sm'><%= @products.count %> Products</p>
```

`@products` is instantiated in the controller method as follows:

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
end
```

In the controller I have a delete action, when it is successful it redirects back to the index page:

```
def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

However my `@products.count` does not update. I am using Rails 7 with Hotwire.

Having a look at my logs, the following happens on redirect:

```
Started GET "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-12-22 18:57:58 +0000
Processing by ProductsController#index as TURBO_STREAM
```

Do instance variables reload automatically on redirect, and if not, how can I make it reload?

Comment: It looks like something may be missing from your view. Did you wrap the p tag in a `turbo-frame` tag?

Comment: `<%= turbo_frame_tag :products do %>
        <p class='text-sm' id='products-count'><%= @products.count %> Products</p>
      <% end %>`

Yep but still doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible there was an issue with the objects destruction. Like an association that will break if you delete it. That's why you should use the destroy method as a conditional to make sure it only redirects if destroy was successful

```
def destroy
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  else
    ... there was an issue destroying
  end
end
```